# How to number a table consecutively by the amount of Objects that are in a mongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ejs

I have a table and want to number it by the amount of records what I have in mongoDB. Everything works except of the numbering...

I tried loops and .length but it breaks my app.

My Schema:

```
var userInputSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,    
    address: String,
    phone: Number
});
```

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">NAME</th>
            <th scope="col">ADDRESS</th>
            <th scope="col">PHONE</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <% userInputs.forEach(function(userInput) { %>
        <tr>
 //this won't work <th scope="row"><% userInput[].length %></th>
            <td><%=userInput.name %></td>
            <td><%=userInput.address %></td>
            <td><%=userInput.phone %></td>

        </tr>
        <% }); %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

It should look like this:

```
#  NAME     ADDRESS       PHONE
1  Gary     Evergrenn     123213
2  Tom      Street        2333434
3  Fox      Jonahill      3434355
```

The column "#" should have the numbering automatically by the amount of records in this mongoDB but I can't make it work.
It's empty or will break the entire page with "internal server error".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try utilizing the index parameter of [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method.

```
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">NAME</th>
        <th scope="col">ADDRESS</th>
        <th scope="col">PHONE</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <% userInputs.forEach(function(userInput, index) { %>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row"><%=++index %></th>
        <td><%=userInput.name %></td>
        <td><%=userInput.address %></td>
        <td><%=userInput.phone %></td>
    </tr>
    <% }); %>
</tbody>
```

You will need to increment the index before printing it.

Comment: upvoted and I deleted my answer, I forgot the "increment the index before printing it" part :P

Comment: Yeah I saw your answer after I posted mine. My answer is on similar lines as of yours.

Comment: Perfect, thank you that worked and thanks to Margon too for your help! I am still a beginner... (<%=++index %> In addition I forgot the "=" anyone who is experiencing the same issue)